# Show advertisement while game loads

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I looked around internet and was always looking like from previous 6 months for a script that could load flash content/game while showing an actual loading screen But I always received a few answers:

1. It is not possible to show an actual loading with Javascript.
2. You can do it only by adding action script to the flash file maybe they are talking about FLA
3. Why Don't you show a fake loading screen that appears and show some
   seconds and then disappears (the most annoying this of such screen
   is that they first make user load 15 seconds then the flash starts
   loading, if it starts loading those 15 seconds still it is worth
   something it is good BUT making them wait double is really bad)

But at last I found something that I was looking forever. A Jquery based script that shows actual loading (shows ad too) and uses swf Object to talk to flash content too. It is really awesome as it doesn't require you to do changes to the FLA, it is just pure outer environment dealing. So now the question arises what's the issue then. Well the issue is that this script was made for pixels, it works if you are using width and height for flash in pixels, while I can't use pixels as I am using %ages (this way user have ability to go full screen optionally by pressing f11).

So as you can see I want that script to work with %ages that is my problem, but as I mentioned earlier I didn't came here right away I have been asking for help (Actually Begging) in over 14 forums from previous few months and of course some good people still exists some people helped me to reach a certain point (but it didn't solve the problem) So now I will provide some Markup:

Here is link to the script that I am talking about http://www.balloontowerdefense.net/jquery-preloader/jquery-preloader.html (It is the link to the creator of this script)

Here is a link to working example (flash based on Pixels)  http://www.balloontowerdefense.net/jquery-preloader/example.html

Some one helped me here but it didn't work 1 month ago. The person told me that I should change the plugin Named as Preroll the changes preferred were these

Modify the plugin to use user-supplied units instead of pixels. To do this, you will need to modify two functions in the plugin, applygameiframe and showgame.

```
applygameiframe should be changed to:

var applygameiframe = function() {
  var gc = '#'+settings.gameframe;
  var iframe = $('<iframe />').attr({
    "id": settings.gameid,
    "src": settings.swf,
    "frameborder": 0,
    "scrolling": "no",
    "marginwidth": 0,
    "marginheight": 0
  }).css({
    "height":'settings.height
    "width": settings.width
  });
  $(gc).append(iframe);
  return true;
};

showgame should be changed to:

var showgame = function() {
    var ac   = '#' + settings.adframe;
    var game = '#' + settings.gameframe;
    $(ac).hide();
    $(game).css({
    "width": settings.width,
    "height": settings.height
    });
};
```

Once those changes are made, the inline CSS should be set to whatever you supply as parameters (i.e., 100%, 50em, etc.).

I did the changes told to be done as described above to the Preroll plugin and after that this is what I get http://files.cryoffalcon.com/MyFootPrint/fullscreen.html

Now if you let the game load (as loading screen appears) all is well done except that in the end, the game doesn't appear, it loads but when it should skip and make the game appear at that time something goes wrong. (For reference you can see this link http://www.balloontowerdefense.net/jquery-preloader/example.html here when the loading finishes then game appears)

Can Someone Fix this problem?

Note: Sorry for not providing JsFiddle but as I live in Afghanistan with 5KBps speed it is not possible for me.

I didn't provided the HTML, CSS and JS that makes up the whole demo page as I thought it will make the question very long but still if you think I should provide Please let me know in comments.

I tried my best to make the question more relevant with Relevant Markups BUT still If I am missing something I would try my best by editing it and providing it you again.

*Being an accountant, I tried my best to use programmers terms, coding is my passion but I am still in learning stage of JS*

UPDATE: After solving the problem here you can see now everything is fine. http://files.cryoffalcon.com/MyFootPrint/newfullscreen.html
Credit: Goes to the one who answered this question.

Comment: What browser and OS are you using and are you seeing any javascript errors in the console?

Comment: +1 for doing programming with 5KB/s

Comment: @brains911 I am using all browsers but just to mention one of them I like Firefox, I am using windows 7 and about errors no I didn't see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be just a pure css problem. You're trying to set the width to 100% while the parent of `div.gamewrapper` has no width or height. That's why the size is 0 and it will not show up.

The trick you need to apply is add the following to your style:

```
html, body, .gamecontent {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

**Update:**
Also, remove `float: left;` from `.gamecontent .game`, and add a width and height of 1px such that it becomes:

```
.gamecontent .game {
    margin:0px auto 0px auto;
    padding:0px;
    overflow:hidden;
    width : 1px;
    height : 1px;
}
```

Comment: Your method solves the problem like 90% it is what is like an answer BUT there is a issue, In google chrome and IE you see the game not hidden still appearing at left side. I don't know why this issue appeared when you solved one. Here is a picture for better understanding. http://content.screencast.com/users/cryoffalcon/folders/Jing/media/d37a533b-8bf3-4edd-94ca-2b166e46eb30/error.png

Comment: That's another css problem. Remove the float : left; from .gamecontent .game {}
Shows well in both Chrome and IE now as well :)

Comment: THANKS FOR QUICK REPLY but you can see it yourself in CHROME AND IE it doesn't solve the issue with float http://files.cryoffalcon.com/MyFootPrint/newfullscreen.html

Comment: and I actually used css but didn't used width and used margin as if i don't do that then it creates scroll bars at the sides, so little addition to your AWESOME idea to which I was negligent ^^

Comment: Found the problem. Add width: 1px; height:1px; to .gamecontent .game

Comment: Hi I have declared you the winner now you don't need to reply me anymore but still just for sake of help as I would be going around again in forums if you load the game in Chrome you can see the game is hanging or you can say it is slow can you tell me why is it okay in firefox while slow in chrome, do you know how to fix it. I am really thankful to you for what you have done and I will do the maximum I can do for you. This one last thing that is not part of this question Just that I saw it now that the game is hanging. Here see http://files.cryoffalcon.com/MyFootPrint/newfullscreen.html

Comment: I would love to help you with this last question, but I don't see what the problem is. They both seem to load pretty much the same for me. Generally seen, there is a difference in the speed of browsers and how they load items.

Comment: Well I will tell you how you can see the difference, well first load it in firefox and then see when its is the monkey with that tank shoots the bloons and then the LETTERS falls from balloon. This thing happens really fast in FIREFOX but if you see this same starting point of shooting balloons and letters falling out its really slow in CHROME, earlier this used to happen when I used to use wmode BUT here it is script not object or embed so I don't know what's going on. I am glad I met a good person here.

Comment: Sorry, they load both just as fast for me. Could be that your computer somehow can't handle the flash animation. And otherwise you could try and update Chrome, see if that works for you. Either way, good luck :)

Comment: Actually I checked it again YOU ARE RIGHT ITS SAME IN BOTH BROWSERS. I am so much glad that my months of problem got settled atlast. Its all because of you, I will add double of what the bounty was as that is what you deserve. Thanks brother its hard to have good people at forums. And last but not the least I didn't understood what's the reason behind using 1px width and height? its just out of curiosity ^^

Comment: The reason behind using 1px width and height, is just a simple trick. It basically makes the size of the game very small, such that it appears that there is no game at all. Actually, there is, but it is very very small (1px x 1px). At some point, the size is changed to the correct size and it magically appears. (Just look at the very top of your screen when the page loads, you'll see a single pixel)

Comment: Hehehehehe WOW that is smart, I will work more and more hard to become a good programmer and developer, I am from Afghanistan we lack lots of other things too except freedom, you people are smarter than us but we will try to at least reach the bench marks. Thanks for your help. Have a wonderful day. ^_^

Answer (score 0):

Well, after an hour and a half of playing [Bloons](http://files.cryoffalcon.com/MyFootPrint/fullscreen.html) on your link (my untouched work load can verify that), I feel it's safe to say that the full screen features work exactly as I'd expect them to. I'm using Chrome 18.0.x.

My experience was: Click link, game loads. The loader took about 2 seconds longer to finish then it took for the "Click Here to Show the Game" button appeared. After, an ad appeared for 10seconds and then I clicked "Play" and it went right to the game. Full screen worked correctly to my knowledge, although when I left full screen the game didn't resize back down - the bottom section was cut off.

I know that doesn't answer your question, but perhaps the issue is only in certain browsers?

Comment: thanks for your information and time, even it is not an answer still you were of help ^^

Answer (score 0):

i found that in FF the problem seems to be the height and width of 100%. I changed the script slightly to:

```
$(game).css({
"width": window.innerWidth,
"height": window.innerHeight
});
```

and now the game shows correctly in FF.

Comment: While this approach works, you're setting the width and height basically to a default value. The effect of supplying settings (the width and height) is now eliminated. If the OP wants to use this plugin for a non full screen purpose, he will not be able to use this script anymore.

Comment: I meant to diagnose the problem while accepting not to deliver the perfect answer :)

Comment: I admit I may not be getting all of the subtleties, but if the OP has a technique that works when it's not full screen, and this is a technique that works when it is full screen, perhaps you could just swap back and forth?

Comment: Your method do make the game appear in FF but it takes away the ability to go fullscreen. The answer above then this solves the problem to a limit but not completely.

Comment: thanks for your time and your answer, I am glad that you tried to help me. I am thankful to you Sir.